# App.use Express not working on heroku

Tags: json, node.js, web-services, express, heroku

I want to deploy my node.js web app on heroku.

My server.js is as follow :

```
 // set variables for environment
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
var pdf = require('express-pdf');

var projectDir = __dirname+'/../..';

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(projectDir+'/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(pdf)
app.use('/pdf', express.static(projectDir + '/data/json/output.pdf'));
app.use('/json', express.static(projectDir+'/data/json'));
require('./saveLastConf')(app, projectDir+'/data/json')
// Set server port
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
console.log('server is running');
```

My code is working locally but when i try heroku local web or when i deploy it on the website my files under `data/json/test.json` cannot be found (404)
(i call my file like that : `https://a.com/json/test.json` )

can anyone help me solve this ?

thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code how you setup https?

Comment: I'm using heroku template, i didn't need to setup anything, I've just followed the tutorial 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

maybe i've just forgot something to configure ?

Comment: Did you pass the port number to process.env.PORT? I don't see any setup to use https in the server.js. Did you try to access the page by http?

Comment: As mentionned on the server.js I've set up the port `(app.set('port',(process.env.PORT || 5000 ));`
And I tried the http but it's alwys the same thing